# how to remove specifc key(;) word from string inside div

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

```
<p>hello how are u</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="fbphotobox"><img id="img__kw_field_id" 
fbphotobox-src=" Uploads/Images/OriginalImages/developer_635647972105434266.jpg;" 
src="Uploads/Images/ResizedImages/developer_635647972105434266.jpg" alt="" /></div>
```

This is my string i need to remove the `;` from `.fbphotobox` `src` i am trying `filter()` but I am not getting this in my code

```
var text = $("#<%=hdnDescription.ClientID%>").val();
var found = text.filter(".fbphotobox");
```

Comment: how is this set in first place? Why not fixing it before rendering it, i mean server side?

Comment: use [String.replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

Comment: By the way, mixing C# with JS (I'm talking about `$("#<%=hdnDescription.ClientID%>")`) is bad style, that's for sure.

Comment: This is not a simple string i want to remove ';' from inside the .fbphotobox this div before that div it maybe contain number of ';' so i dont want change thous. My problem is that image not coming due to that ';' i need to remove ; from that fbphotobox-src that inside tha the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to fix it on server side.

However you can use,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Read attribute and replace text
  $('#img__kw_field_id').attr('fbphotobox-src', function(){
   return $(this).attr('fbphotobox-src').replace(";","");
  }); 
  
  alert($('#img__kw_field_id').attr('fbphotobox-src'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="img__kw_field_id" fbphotobox-src=" Uploads/Images/OriginalImages/developer_635647972105434266.jpg;" src="Uploads/Images/ResizedImages/developer_635647972105434266.jpg" alt="" />
```

Answer (score -1):

try something like this:

```
var text = "hello; dafsdf sd sdf sdf sdf dsf!";
var result = text.replace(";", "");
```

Comment: Thanks for u reply there are diff layers of div i want to replace from .fbphotobox that div i dont wont to replace all

Answer (score -1):

try using

```
var text = $("#<%=hdnDescription.ClientID%>").val();
var found = text.replace(";","");
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Well, for all that I see the task is to replace `;` inside _fbphotobox-src_, not in empty value.

Comment: Please don't post code-only answer and add an explanation.